# Join 2 arrays by key and value (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 objects

```
{
  "_id": "58b7f36b3354c24630f6f3b0",
  "name": "refcode",
  "caption": "Reference",
  "type": "string",
  "search": false,
  "required": false,
  "table": true,
  "expansion": true
},
```

and

```
{
  "_id": "58b7f36b3354c24630f6f3c8",
  "vacancyid": "0",
  "refcode": "THIS IS MY REF",
  "position": "Test",
  "jobtype": "Temp",
  "department": "Industrial",
  "branch": "Office",
  "startdate": "02/12/2013",
  "contactname": "Person Name",
  "contactemail": "person@domain",
  "Q_V_TYP": "Daily",
  "score": 0
},
```

Object one defines what a field should be and what it is called

The second object is a job description.

What i need is to match a field to each key (this even sounds confusing i my head, so here is an example)

```
{
  "_id": "58b7f36b3354c24630f6f3c8",
  "vacancyid": "0",
  "refcode": {
    "_id": "58b7f36b3354c24630f6f3b0",
    "name": "refcode",
    "caption": "Reference",
    "type": "string",
    "search": false,
    "required": false,
    "table": true,
    "expansion": true,
    "value": "THIS IS MY REF"
    }
  },      
  "position": "Test",
  "jobtype": "Temp",
  "department": "Industrial",
  "branch": "Office",
  "startdate": "02/12/2013",
  "contactname": "Person Name",
  "contactemail": "person@domain",
  "Q_V_TYP": "Daily",
  "score": 0
},
```

Comment: What is the key that bound one object with the other? What I mean is, what is the foreign key

Comment: the 1st objects value for "name" matched with the 2nd objects key - so in that example refcode is what matches the 2

Comment: Then what's the problem, if you have a way to match them what's stoping you from doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
var def = {
  "_id": "58b7f36b3354c24630f6f3b0",
  "name": "refcode",
  "caption": "Reference",
  "type": "string",
  "search": false,
  "required": false,
  "table": true,
  "expansion": true
};

var jobDesc = {
  "_id": "58b7f36b3354c24630f6f3c8",
  "vacancyid": "0",
  "refcode": "THIS IS MY REF",
  "position": "Test",
  "jobtype": "Temp",
  "department": "Industrial",
  "branch": "Office",
  "startdate": "02/12/2013",
  "contactname": "Person Name",
  "contactemail": "person@domain",
  "Q_V_TYP": "Daily",
  "score": 0
};

var jobDescKeysArr = Object.keys(jobDesc);

if (jobDescKeysArr.indexOf(def.name) !== -1) {
  // A match.
  def.value = jobDesc[def.name];

  jobDesc[def.name] = Object.assign({}, def);

  console.log(jobDesc)
}
```